# identifier expected in jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am new to JFreecharts in java.Am trying execute the code for piechart but its giving error "identifier expected and illegal start of expression".can anybody help me .

```
 import org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame;
 import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
 import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
 import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;
import org.jfree.dataset;


public class test {
/**
* The starting point for the demo.
*
* @param args ignored.
*/
// create a dataset...
DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset;
dataset.setValue("Category 1", 43.2);
dataset.setValue("Category 2", 27.9);
dataset.setValue("Category 3", 79.5);
// create a chart...
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
"Sample Pie Chart",
dataset,
true, // legend?
true, // tooltips?
false // URLs?
);
// create and display a frame...
ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("First", chart);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line doesn't refer to any class or package:

```
import org.jfree.dataset;
```

Then your class is not well formed, there should be a constructor, and at least a main() method.  This is nothing related to JFreeChart, just basic Java programming so you should go through a good tutorial about that first.